# Why does the 1/2 vanish when finding this antiderivative?

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrating:

```
dx/sqrt(x)+2x
```

I substituted u=sqrt(x) and got u/2u+2u^2

I pulled out u and got 1/2+2u and simplified to 1/2(1+u)

but my book says the answer is ln(1+u), not ln(1+u)/2.

Where did that 1/2 go, and/or why did it cancel out?

Comment: If $u = \sqrt{x}$, $du = \dfrac{dx}{2 \sqrt{x}}$

Comment: After the substitution you should have $2u/(u+2u^2)$, not $u/(2u+2u^2)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did drop the 2 when I substituted.  I don't know if I can upvote you and the other commenter for leaving comments, but if so just let me know.